# JS Error on Replacing Div Class Content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to replace html content within a class. It works when I put something simple, such as `<p>0</p>`.

But when I put the following:

```
$('.festi-cart-menu-item').html('<a id="festi-cart"    class="
        festi-cart
        festi-cart-customize  
        festi-cart-menu  
        festi-cart-click        woocart-show    "
    href="https://example.com/cart/"
>
    <div style=" line-height: 20px !important; " class="festi-cart-content">

        <img class="festi-cart-icon" width="20" height="20"  align="absmiddle" src="//example.com/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-woocartpro/static/images/icons/user/custom_icon.png?1524043934" /><img style="display: none;" class="festi-cart-icon festi-on-hover" width="20" height="20"  align="absmiddle" src="//example.com/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-woocartpro/static/images/icons/user/on_hover/custom_icon.png?1524043934" />



        <span
            class="festi-cart-position budgeCounter position-right">
            <p>
                0            </p>
        </span>

    <span class="festi-cart-text-before-total">
                    </span>
        <span class="festi-cart-text-after-total">
                    </span>


        <span class="festi-cart-dropdown-arrow"><img src="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/path-2.png" alt="dropdown"></span>
</div>
</a> ');
```

It's giving an error.

Can you help point what's wrong?

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: The error posted is: (index):1 Uncaught ReferenceError: formSubmit is not defined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick ((index):1)

Comment: That seems unrelated. First off: make it one string, so remove all unnecessary spaces. Also add the error to your post and create a working sample.

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify your string variable is multiline.
This is possible since ES6 with

```
let string = `bla
bla
bla`;
```

Without ES6, something you could do would be

```
var string = '<html>'+
                  '<body>'+
                      '<input>'+
                  '</body>'+
             '</html>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem comes from misunderstanding how `""` and `''` works in this case. These are mainly used for creating strings in single line and for multiple lines you should use double back-tick  ``` `` ```

If you want to make this work and code it the right way you can declare another variable e.g. `var template` and compose your template with ES6 syntax ``` `` ```.

In your case it would look like this:

```
var template = `<a>...</a> ` //just put your template here

$('.festi-cart-menu-item').html(template);
```